# Why include version numbers of scripts when embedding in page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I notice when scripts are included in a page, for example, a jquery script, it includes a version number. For example:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='superfish.js?ver=3.9'></script>
```

What is the advantage of including the version number when inserting it into the HTML of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the version changes, the URL changes, so the browser won't think it's got a cached copy. Thus, when the developers of the site release an updated version, it works properly — the new pages are ensured that everybody will download the updated JavaScript.

(Browsers consider the whole URL, including the query string, to be the "key" for the local cache.)